# Will marriage exist in Kaliyuga ? What does scriptures say about it?

Tags: marriage, kali-yuga

What does scriptures say about the institution of marriage ?
Will marriage exist in Kaliyuga according to scriptures ?

What will be happening in marriage in Kaliyuga ?